# How do I get results in Views (Contextual Filters) regarded titles in URL?

Tags: 7, views

I want the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to give me results by criteria of title of the `node`. I want to display all results from the `nodes` with the same title.

So I used the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, and put what is in title fields into `url`.

But when I tried to set `contextual filters` it doesn't return any results. I tried many options, for example : `Type - Raw value from URL, Path component: 1`, and did some variation with that, but nothing worked.

What do I have to do?